# Include Ajax in Wordpress in a Blank Theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a one page wordpress theme that I start develop from blank.
It's really basic. Just have two files: 
index.php
style.css

In another themes the plugin "contact form 7" do all the job without reload the page.
But when I activate my theme and try to use the contact form 7, after click on submit button the page reload and my url get a `#wpcf7-f519-o1`.
So I believe that some code is missing in my theme.

Basically this is my theme:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body> </body>

</html>
```

I don't have any call to footer or header or functions because I put all the code on a simple page.

So the question is: What should I do to make ajax work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.

Step 1 - insert 
`<?php wp_head(); ?>`  after `<head>` tag

Step 2 - insert `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` before `</body>` tag

```
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
your code...
</head>

<body> 
your code...
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, you would still need to include the header/footer which is where Wordpress initializes itself. If I were you, instead of developing from the gorund up, I would use something like BlankSlate to give you all the basics: https://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate/